# is There any option to add dynamic string into the String.xml file

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I provided the dynamic application id in the authorities and now I need to pass the same authority to the string.xml, how can I pass it

this peace of code of the androidmanifest.xml file

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
     >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/freshchat_file_provider_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```

string.xml

```
  <string name="freshchat_file_provider_authority"></string>
```

can you please tell me